# Django AttributeError:'Campaign' object has no attribute 'ads'

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create in a nested serializer in Django Rest Framework but I keep getting this error. I know why it's throwing it but, i thought Django would handle the one-to-many relationship.

> AttributeError at /api/campaigns
>   Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `ads` on serializer `CampaignSerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Campaign` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'Campaign' object has no attribute 'ads'.

```
class Campaign(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    locations = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    budget = models.IntegerField()
    land_page = models.URLField()
    keywords = models.TextField()
    CPM = models.IntegerField()
    CPC = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    commission = models.IntegerField()
    pay_off = models.IntegerField()
    advertiser = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date_time = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = "campaigns"

class ADS(models.Model):

    advertiser = models.ForeignKey(User)
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description_1 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    description_2 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    display_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    final_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    mobile_url = models.URLField(blank=True)


class Meta:
    db_table = "ads"
```

These are my serializers

```
class ADSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    adsImages = AdsImagesSerializer(read_only=True,many=True)

class Meta:
    model = ADS
    fields = ("headline","description_1","description_2","display_url","final_url","mobile_url","advertiser","adsImages")


class CampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    advertiser = AdvertiserProfile(read_only=True,required=False)
    ads = ADSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    model = Campaign
    fields = ("name","type","start_date","end_date","locations","budget","land_page","keywords","CPM","CPC","description","commission","pay_off","ads","advertiser",)

def get_validation_exclusions(self, *args, **kwargs):
    exclusions = super(CampaignSerializer,self).get_validation_exclusions()

    return exclusions + ['advertiser']

def create(self, validated_data):
    ads_data = validated_data.pop('ads')
    campaign = Campaign.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for ad_data in ads_data:
        ADS.objects.create(campaign=campaign, **ad_data)
    return campaign
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this, with a related name in the model

```
campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, related_name="ads")
```

I think it didn't worked last time because the reverse relationship was not working without a related_name.